# Contact structures associated to taut foliations

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, foliations

[Eliashberg and Thurston](https://doi.org/http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/ulect/013) showed that a [taut foliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut_foliation?wprov=sfti1) may be deformed to tight (positive and negative) contact structures. [Vogel](https://doi.org/10.2140/gt.2016.20.2439) proved that for a taut foliation without torus leaves, the associated contact structures are unique up to isotopy. My question is roughly: if a taut foliation is deformed through taut foliations without torus leaves, are the associated contact structures unique up to isotopy?

To be more specific, suppose one has a taut foliation carried by an oriented [branched surface](https://doi.org/10.2307/1971476) not carrying any tori, so that the complement is a product taut sutured manifold. Any oriented lamination carried by the branched surface extends to a taut foliation, which is presumably deformation equivalent to any other one. Examples of such laminar branched surfaces without vertices occur for [veering triangulations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6439) by deforming the oriented triangulation to be generic (double along the torus boundary to get a closed manifold).
[image]
Then can one associate unique (up to isotopy) positive and negative tight contact structures (in the sense of Eliashberg-Thurston) to such branched surfaces?

Comment: Suppose that $M$ has Thurston norm ball with adjacent fibered faces. Suppose that $F$ is a taut surface on the boundary of both. So $F$ is the compact leaf of two distinct depth one foliations. Is there a way to interpolate between these? (Say by using “shifts” along annuli?) If so that kind of “connectedness” result, plus your desired uniqueness result would combine in a way that seems too strong…

Comment: I think these two depth one foliations will be carried by distinct branched surfaces.

Comment: I think that a pair of depth one foliations may be deformation equivalent *without* both being carried by a single branched surface.  One tool to produce such is "shifts in annuli".  Now, by definition, annulus shifts only effect the foliation in an $I$--bundle region.  But every finite depth foliation ends with a product, so perhaps there is some hope that (a) changing weights in branched surfaces and (b) annulus shifts suffice to realise all deformations.

Comment: Okay, so maybe my “rough” question might have a negative answer. So then the question is what deformations of taut foliations preserve the contact structure. But the question still stands as stated for families of taut foliations carried by a single branched surface.